# what is the reason for one day delay in date value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

below is my sample code.

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate * dateFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2016-01-17"];
NSLog(@"Date : %d",dateFormatted);
```

The output is 2016-01-16 18:30:00 +0000. How to get date Formatt 2016-01-17 . what is the reason for one day delay. please help me.

Comment: What is your time zone?

Comment: Time Zone: india. am date is fixed but result logger print is one day delay. what is the reason. any timezone use but date is constant string values.

Comment: Well, India is +5:30 or so. so Jan, 17, 00:00 for you will be Jan 16, 18:30 in Greenwich. You have to tell the formatter to print in your timezone.

Comment: a NSDate is just a moment in time, counting seconds from 1/1/1970. if you print it it will display it's value in UTC.

Comment: Baskar, the very first thing that you should learn is that India is 5 1/2 hours ahead of GMT, so midnight of the 17th in India _is_ 18:30 on the 16th GMT. The result is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't create the NSDate from the NSString without timezone mark.

1. Add timezone to the NSString [like "-0800"](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns):

   ```
   e.g. "2016-01-17 -0800"  --> "yyyy-MM-dd Z"
   ```
2. Add code:

   ```
   [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];// change timezone u want
   ```

Comment: my date is contstant string. what is the reason for one day delay.

Comment: Some examples when UTC is 23:00 on Monday:

     Cairo, Egypt: UTC+02; 01:00 on Tuesday
     Wellington, New Zealand: UTC+12; 11:00 on Tuesday

Comment: my system and local timezone Asia/kolkata (GMT+5.30).

Comment: @Baskar So it is.  `18:30 + 5:30 = 24:00`  ==> `2016-01-16 18:30 +0000` --> `2016-01-17 00:00 +0530`

Answer (score 1):

```
   NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate * dateFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2016-01-17"];
    NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:dateFormatted];
    NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

    NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:dateFormatted];

    NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;
    NSDate *destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:dateFormatted] ;

    NSLog(@"Date : %@",destinationDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code...!

I am forcing the Date to be 2016-01-17 in first 2 scenarios. U can check and use if it is useful to you..!

```
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate * sourceDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2016-01-17"];

    int daysToAdd = 1;
    NSDate *presentDate = [sourceDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd]; //Output 2016-01-17 18:30:00 +0000

    NSDate * dateFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2016-01-17"];
    NSCalendar *calendar1 = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components1 = [calendar1 components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:dateFormatted];
    [components1 setHour:24];//24
    [components1 setMinute:00];//00
    NSDate *presentDate1 = [calendar1 dateFromComponents:components1]; //Output 2016-01-17 18:30:00 +0000

    //The input
    NSString *myDateAsAStringValue = @"2016-01-17";

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    //Getting Date
    NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: myDateAsAStringValue]; // Output 2016-01-17 00:00:00 +0000

    //create the formatter for the output
    NSDateFormatter *out_df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [out_df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSString *dateStr=[out_df stringFromDate:myDate];//2016-01-17
```

Hope it helps you...!